# How to set multiple cookies in java?

Tags: java, cookies

I have to following code to set cookies in java:

```
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "userid=xy");
```

But I need to set multiple cookies, how should I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#addRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
 public void addRequestProperty(String key, String value)
```

> Adds a general request property specified by a key-value pair. This
>   method will not overwrite existing values associated with the same
>   key.

Answer (score 0):

The use of cookies have been deprecated since Java 1.5.  It is recommended that state information be encoded in request parameters.

Comment: Not as far as I've heard or seen.  Is there a source you can reference?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to set multiple cookies in a single Cookie HTTP header:

```
Cookie: <name>=<value> [;<name>=<value>]...
```